# Windows Forms: Designing A Full Screen Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

My program Is full screen, And It's difficult designing it in the designer because you can only see about a half of the form. Is there a way to scale down the designer, and to make it scale up when the code is ran?

[image]

Comment: You can go to `View` => `FullScreen` (or press `Shift + Alt + Enter`). Not sure if this will solve your problem or not, but it may be useful in the meantime

Comment: Full screen for what screen size? Don't design for a large screen size, design smaller form, use suitable dock and anchor for control. Use `TableLayoutPanel` and `FlowLayoutPanel` if needed.

Comment: You can undock the designer window and maximize it.

Comment: But if I design on a smaller screen and, for example, put a label that covers half of the frame in the designer, it won't be half of the screen when I run it.

Comment: When I posted my answer, I hadn't yet seen Reza's comment for some reason (it didn't appear). But since he effectively gave the same answer that I provided as an Answer, I removed my answer so that Reza gets the points he deserves for answering sooner.

Comment: Why don't you try reducing the Form Size?

Comment: @Jazimov No need to remove your answer, I was not going to post an answer. Comments also doesn't have any reputation score. So feel free to undelete your answer. JFYI, I've already upvoted the answer.

Comment: @Reza: So kind--and thank you for the explanation and upvote. Answer undeleted.

Answer (score 3):

Your main issue is your desire to design a "full screen" program. Ask yourself--what does "full screen" mean? You soon will realize that it can mean 1024x768 resolution, 1920x1080, or any of a number of other common resolutions. Add mobile devices to the mix, and you should see the issue here.

Read up on Winforms anchor, dock, and control metrics properties (size [height, width] and location [top, left]) to determine how best to lay out your form so that it auto-adapts to a full-screen canvas. The TableLayoutPanel and various third-party components (DevExpress, Syncfusion, ComponentOne, etc.) can help you too.